# Setting target mail server PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, postfix-mta

I have a list of mail servers that I would like to send an email to depending on the recipient address. For example, I have this array:

```
<?php
$_hosts = array("example.com" => "mx1.example.com", "domain.com" => "mx1.domain.com");
?>
```

So I would like when mailing `user@example.com`, to connect to `mx1.example.com` and drop the email there. I'm using PHPMailer to send an email to `user@example.com` using the following code:

```
$mail = new 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = '587';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
...
$mail->addAddress("user@example.com");
```

This code works perfectly, except that it sends the message to the mail server at `example.com`. How can I instruct PHPMailer to send this email to `mx1.example.com` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do whatever you need to look up the address in your array, then set `Host` to the corresponding server you want to send through. If you leave it set to `localhost` it will always send through there.

Comment: Thank you! I would actually like to send through localhost all the time, but I want it to connect to a specific mail server to drop the mail, instead of setting up MX records, for example. Is what I'm asking for even possible, maybe at least over telnet?

Comment: That's a different question. This is something you would need to handle in your local mail server - postfix has transport maps that can provide routing like this. You could fudge it by setting up fixed MX records in your local DNS.

Comment: Transport maps is perfect. Thanks a lot, @Synchro! I'm accepting this as an answer; it would be really great if you could add this information in your answer so that people having the same problem can find a solution.